# What's the difference between too and so?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to explain the subtle difference between "too" and "so" in the following sentence (from a child's book) to someone whose first language is not English. But I'm struggling.

"That's not my fairy, her dress is *too* shiny"
"That's my fairy, her wand is *so* sparkly"

How would I explain this difference?

Comment: whose, not who's.

Comment: This is the one place on the internet where grammatical mistakes are a sin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **too** *adverb*
> 1 (as submodifier) To a higher degree than is desirable, permissible, or possible; excessively.
> ‘he was driving too fast’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/too)
>
> **so** *adverb*
> 1 (as submodifier) To such a great extent.
> ‘the words tumbled out so fast that I could barely hear them’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so)

The essential difference is that *too* carries the notion of being excessive while *so* simply conveys the notion of a great extent.

Comment: "That dress is too too pretty."  "That dress is so so pretty."

Comment: @HotLicks What do you think of the train, kiddo? *Too too sounds so so*. :)

Comment: I think I can understand what you're saying.  I think I can.

Comment: @HotLicks Nice one. :D